# Standard Deviation Java

Tags: java, statistics, standard-deviation

I must write a program that reads a set of floating-point values (total 10. It is fixed) and then calculate and display the average of the values, standard deviation, the smallest of the values, the largest of the values, the second largest of the values
It should have a loop. In the loop, prompt user to enter a number (a floating number that can have fractional part) and save the number in a variable (with double type). I have done it but I am having trouble on implementing a loop to be able to take in values easier because I do not know how to save them while it is being calculated through looping. So now my code looks very ugly and redundant.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Statistics {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        float average = 0;
        float smallest = 0;
        float largest = 0;
        float scndLargest = 0;
        float a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j = 0;
        System.out.println("Enter values.");
        a = s.nextFloat();
        b = s.nextFloat();
        c = s.nextFloat();
        d = s.nextFloat();
        e = s.nextFloat();
        f = s.nextFloat();
        g = s.nextFloat();
        h = s.nextFloat();
        i = s.nextFloat();
        j = s.nextFloat();

        average = (a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j) / 10;
        float min1 = Math.min(a, b);
        float min2 = Math.min(c, d);
        float min3 = Math.min(e, f);
        float min4 = Math.min(g, h);
        float min5 = Math.min(i, j);

        float min6 = Math.min(min1, min2);
        float min7 = Math.min(min3, min4);
        float min8 = Math.min(min7, min5);

        smallest = Math.min(min6, min8);
        System.out.println("The smallest value is: " + smallest);

        float max1 = Math.max(a, b); //2
        float max2 = Math.max(max1, c);
        float max3 = Math.max(max2, d); //4
        float max4 = Math.max(max3, e);
        float max5 = Math.max(max4, f); //6
        float max6 = Math.max(max5, g); //6
        float max7 = Math.max(max6, h); //8
        float max8 = Math.max(max7, i);
        largest = Math.max(max8, j); //10

        System.out.println("The largest value is: " + largest);

        scndLargest = Math.min(largest, max8);
        System.out.println("The second largest value is: " + scndLargest);
        System.out.println("The average of all the values is: " + average);

        double a1 = Math.pow(a - average, 2);
        double b1 = Math.pow(a - average, 2);
        double c1 = Math.pow(a - average, 2);
        double d1 = Math.pow(a - average, 2);
        double e1 = Math.pow(a - average, 2);
        double f1 = Math.pow(a - average, 2);
        double g1 = Math.pow(a - average, 2);
        double h1 = Math.pow(a - average, 2);
        double i1 = Math.pow(a - average, 2);
        double j1 = Math.pow(a - average, 2);

        double sum1 = Math.pow(a1 /10, 2);
        double sum2 = Math.pow(b1 /10, 2);
        double sum3 = Math.pow(c1 /10, 2);
        double sum4 = Math.pow(d1 /10, 2);
        double sum5 = Math.pow(e1 /10, 2);
        double sum6 = Math.pow(f1 /10, 2);
        double sum7 = Math.pow(g1 /10, 2);
        double sum8 = Math.pow(h1 /10, 2);
        double sum9 = Math.pow(i1 /10, 2);
        double sum10 = Math.pow(j1 /10, 2);

        double total = (sum1 + sum2 + sum3 + sum4 + sum5 + sum6 + sum7 + sum8 + sum9 + sum10);
        double squaredVariance = (total) / 10;
        double newTotal = Math.sqrt(squaredVariance);
        System.out.printf("Standard deviation is: ");
        System.out.printf("%.2f", newTotal);


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of naming every variable, try an [array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

```
float inputs = new float[10];
for(int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
    inputs[i] = s.nextFloat();
```

Then once you have an array, you can find the minimum with a loop as well

```
float min = inputs[0];
for(float f : inputs)
    min = Math.min(f, min);
```

If you wanted to get fancy, you could also use streams to find min/max (might only work on an array of doubles)

```
double min = Arrays.stream(inputs).min().getAsDouble();
```

Comment: That is where I'm stumped, I forgot to mention the part where we are not allowed to use an array...

Comment: What are the limitations?  Is it only arrays that are banned, or lists as well?

Comment: Arrays and lists are both not allowed.

Comment: @Elias if that includes all lists (linked lists and so on), then I don't think there's an easy way to get around it, without rewriting your own list class or something.  If this is a homework problem, the point may be to show how painful it is to not have arrays and lists

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the entire class because I'm currently in CompSci and Statistics so it intrigued me.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {

  static float[] input = new float[10];
  static Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      input[i] = s.nextFloat();
    }
    Arrays.sort(input);

    System.out.println("Largest: " + input[9]);
    System.out.println("Smallest: " + input[0]);
    System.out.println("Second largest: " + input[8]);
    System.out.println("Average: " + getTotal()/10);
    System.out.printf("Standard deviation %.2f", Math.sqrt(getTotal()/10));
  }

  static public float getTotal() {
    float total = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      total += input[i];
    }

    return total;
  }
}
```

Comment: That is a very good solution however I forgot to mention arrays and lists are not allowed. That is why I have no idea how to go about doing this.